# self-written appender does not utilize specified layout

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I wrote my own appender to be able to output the log in a WPF `TextBox`. Here it is:

```
public class TextBoxAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    private TextBox _tb;
    public TextBoxAppender(TextBox tb)
    {
        _tb = tb;
    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        _tb.Text += loggingEvent.RenderedMessage + "\n";
    }
}
```

I initialized the log and added the appender like so:

```
var myTextBox = ... // get WPF TextBox from somewhere
var type = GetType();
var assembly = type.Assembly;
var loggerRepo = LogManager.GetRepository(assembly);
var rootLogger = ((Hierarchy)loggerRepo).Root;
Log = LogManager.GetLogger(assembly, type);
var tbAppender = new TextBoxAppender(myTextBox);

rootLogger.AddAppender(tbAppender);
rootLogger.Hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

And it works. I did not specify any layout, so it just uses some default layout: If I write `Log.Debug("My Message")` then the output is just `"My Message"`.

Now I want to specify my own layout. So I wrote these lines:

```
PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
layout.ConversionPattern = "%level - %message%newline"; // my layout
layout.ActivateOptions();
tbAppender.Layout = layout;
tbAppender.ActivateOptions();
```

and put them in the empty line between `var tbAppender = ...` and `rootLogger.AddAppender...`. But it doesn't change the layout at all! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the loggingEvent is passed to all your active appenders, and hence does have any knowledge of the layout (which is a property of the appender).

I think the solution is to call the appenders RenderLoggingEvent method, ie change

```
 _tb.Text += loggingEvent.RenderedMessage + "\n";
```

to

```
 _tb.Text += RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent) + "\n";
```